# How do I make this more efficient- Consider the fraction, n/d, where n and d are positive integers

Tags: javascript, performance, data-structures, fractions

How do I make this more efficient

> Consider the fraction, n/d, where n and d are positive integers. If
> n<d and HCF(n,d) = 1, it is called a reduced proper fraction.  If we
> list the set of reduced proper fractions for d<8 in ascending order of
> size, we get
>
> 1/8, 1/7, 1/6, 1/5, 1/4, 2/7, 1/3, 3/8, 2/5,  3/7, 1/2, 4/7, 3/5, 5/8,
> 2/3, 5/7, 3/4, 4,5, 5/6, 6/7, 7/8
>
> If can be seen that there are 21 elements in this set.
> Write a
> program to count the number of proper fractions for a given number d.

```
function GCD(a,b) {
    while(a != b){
        if(a > b)
                a -= b;
        else
                    b -= a;
    }
    return a;
}

function countProperFractions(d) {
count = 0;
        num = [];
        den = [];
    for( j = 1; j <= d; j++){
        for( n = 1; n < j; n++) {
                num.push(n);
                    den.push(j);
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
            if(GCD(num[i],den[i])==1)
                count+=1;
        }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: What *efficiency* problems do you have?

Comment: It's not passing the test cases

Comment: Please remember we have absolutely no idea what you're talking about unless you explain things to us. What test cases? What failures? What problems?

Comment: I'm talking about the time complexity

Comment: We can't fix problems we can't see. You're going to have to give us [a more complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How do I reduce the number of for loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#:%7E:text=Euler%27s%20totient%20function%20is%20a,defining%20the%20RSA%20encryption%20system.) function to get the count of positive integers which are relatively prime to a given number n.

Some sort of prefix array will help you get to the solution faster.

Here is an [implementation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/eulers-totient-function/).